# MongoDb: can't change its oplog size

Tags: mongodb

I need to change the oplog size by operating on existing members. (without using additional members with pre-confiugred needed oplog size)

I have failed use of this official manual: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/
which states that oplog.rs can be found while running in standalone mode
which is wrong. at least in my case.
So please, anybody point me in right direction to succeed my task

There is the actions i've performed to show the problem

at first a have logged into SECONDARY member and dumped its oplog.rs to make sure it exists:

```
# mongodump --db local --collection 'oplog.rs' --port 27018
connected to: 127.0.0.1:27018
Thu Nov  5 13:26:44.369 DATABASE: local  to     dump/local
Thu Nov  5 13:26:44.370         local.oplog.rs to dump/local/oplog.rs.bson
Thu Nov  5 13:26:44.410                  273 objects
Thu Nov  5 13:26:44.410         Metadata for local.oplog.rs to dump/local/oplog.rs.metadata.json
```

check to see what have been dumped:

```
# find dump/ -ls
917559    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Nov  5 13:26 dump/
917560    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Nov  5 13:26 dump/local
917561 9516 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root      9742693 Nov  5 13:26 dump/local/oplog.rs.bson
917562    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root           79 Nov  5 13:26 dump/local/oplog.rs.metadata.json
```

so the oplog.rs exists on secondary and has some data in it.
remove dump directory..

```
# rm -rf dump
```

then, switch to standalone ...

```
# mongod --port 37018 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/mongod-oplog-test2&
[4] 25587
# Thu Nov  5 13:29:41.690 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=25587 port=37018 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb/mongod-oplog-test2 64-bit host=mongohost.net.local
Thu Nov  5 13:29:41.690 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.14
Thu Nov  5 13:29:41.690 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Thu Nov  5 13:29:41.690 [initandlisten] build info: Linux buildvm-24.phx2.fedoraproject.org 3.19.5-200.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Apr 20 19:51:56 UTC 2015 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Thu Nov  5 13:29:41.690 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Thu Nov  5 13:29:41.690 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb/mongod-oplog-test2", port: 37018 }
Thu Nov  5 13:29:41.715 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/mongod-oplog-test2/journal
Thu Nov  5 13:29:41.715 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Thu Nov  5 13:29:41.739 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 38018
Thu Nov  5 13:29:41.741 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 37018
```

check to see if oplog.rs can be found via mongodump, expecting to see the same results as at previous run on replica mode:

```
# mongodump --db local --collection 'oplog.rs' --port 37018
Thu Nov  5 13:51:17.614 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54388 #10 (1 connection now open)
Thu Nov  5 13:51:17.615 DATABASE: local  to     dump/local

# find dump/ -ls
917559    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Nov  5 13:51 dump/
917560    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Nov  5 13:51 dump/local
```

and we see nothing here.

Check to see if we can reach oplog.rs at all...

```
#  mongo --port 37018
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.14
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:37018/test
> use local;
switched to db local
> show tables;
startup_log
>
```

and there is no oplog.rs collection....

so is time to fix the manual or did i understood something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem and i hope this case will be documented as well:

my mongo.conf contains the directive:

```
directoryperdb = true
```

so i should use the directive --directoryperdb in the command line to run standalone:

```
mongod --directoryperdb --port 37018 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/mongod-oplog-test2
```